# API Key enabled, but requests without key still running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In my API Gateway console, I did the following:

- Created an API key
- Associated the key with a deployed API stage
- Checked the key's "Enabled" checkbox
- For each method of each resource of my API, required the API key for authentication

I expected `curl https://my-api-gateway-url/my-resource` to 403, since I didn't include the `x-api-key` header, but it was a 200 instead. My Lambda function behind API Gateway ended up running when it shouldn't have run without the API key.

How can I ensure the key is required to authenticate all requests?

EDIT: I was following the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html

Comment: did you re-deploy?

Comment: ohh you did.. glad it worked :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just answered my own question. Posting my answer here as I know I'm not the only one wondering about this, like [this person](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=657600&#657600).

The answer is to redeploy your API. Although redeploying sounds obvious, the docs completely skip the vital last step, so it's easy to overlook.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Thanks for your feedback regarding the documentation. I will pass it on to our documentation team to make sure that all the necessary steps are covered.

Best

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: That is SOOO annoying....Spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why my API KEY validation was not working...deployed API again and fixed

Comment: Thanks for sharing. @Jurgen: I think we need a warning, something like "Warning: Undeployed changes"

Comment: This issue is endemic with terraform and API Gateway. You pretty much always need to redeploy the API to a stage when you change anything... and terraform doesn't automatically redeploy when there changes. There are techniques to force a redeploy but they are kind of kludgey - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910937/terraform-not-deploying-api-gateway-stage