# Terraform not deploying api gateway stage

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform

I have been trying to create an API Gateway endpoint using terraform. Everything seems to be working except the last part of deploying a stage.

After I run terraform  apply I go into the console and I find that the deployment has not happened. I need to manually click on Deploy Api in order to get it working.

Here's the terraform file for the api gateway.

```
variable "region" {}
variable "account_id" {}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api" {
  name = "online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api"
  description = "The endpoint that test has to hit when new client reports are available."
  depends_on = ["aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_test_endpoint_lambda"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "test_client_report_resource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "test_client_report"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "test_client_report_method" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "test_client_report_resource_integration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  type = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_test_endpoint_lambda.arn}/invocations"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = "${file("${path.module}/generic_request_mapping_template.vm")}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "200" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "test_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.200.status_code}"
  selection_pattern = ""
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_integration.test_client_report_resource_integration"]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "500" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "500"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "test_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.500.status_code}"
  selection_pattern = ".*?Error.*"
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_integration.test_client_report_resource_integration"]
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api_gateway" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_test_endpoint_lambda.arn}"
    principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_integration.test_client_report_resource_integration.integration_http_method}${aws_api_gateway_resource.test_client_report_resource.path}"
    depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api"]
}

#This is the part that doesn't seem to work. 
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "qa5" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_test_client_report_endpoint_api.id}"
  stage_name = "qa5"
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.test_client_report_method"]
}
```

## Edit

Added the graph in :

```
    digraph {
        compound = "true"
        newrank = "true"
        subgraph "root" {
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_deployment.qa5" [label = "aws_api_gateway_deployment.qa5", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" [label = "aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" [label = "aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" [label = "aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method" [label = "aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200" [label = "aws_api_gateway_method_response.200", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500" [label = "aws_api_gateway_method_response.500", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource" [label = "aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api" [label = "aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role" [label = "aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.publish_to_sns_policy" [label = "aws_iam_role_policy.publish_to_sns_policy", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.write_to_cloudwatch_policy" [label = "aws_iam_role_policy.write_to_cloudwatch_policy", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda" [label = "aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" [label = "aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws" [label = "provider.aws", shape = "diamond"]
            "[root] module.sns.aws_sns_topic.online_tax_qa5_sbr_client_report" [label = "aws_sns_topic.online_tax_qa5_sbr_client_report", shape = "box"]
            "[root] module.sns.provider.aws" [label = "provider.aws", shape = "diamond"]
            "[root] provider.aws (disabled)" [label = "provider.aws (disabled)", shape = "diamond"]
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_deployment.qa5" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_deployment.qa5" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_deployment.qa5" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_default_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.sbr_client_report_resource_integration_error_response" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.200" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method.sbr_client_report_method"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_method_response.500" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.publish_to_sns_policy" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.publish_to_sns_policy" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.publish_to_sns_policy" -> "[root] module.sns.aws_sns_topic.online_tax_qa5_sbr_client_report"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.write_to_cloudwatch_policy" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role_policy.write_to_cloudwatch_policy" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_iam_role.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_role"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_integration.sbr_client_report_resource_integration"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_resource.sbr_client_report_resource"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.online_tax_sbr_client_report_endpoint_api"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" -> "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.onlinetax_sbr_endpoint_lambda"
            "[root] module.lambda.aws_lambda_permission.allow_api_gateway" -> "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.lambda.provider.aws" -> "[root] provider.aws (disabled)"
            "[root] module.sns.aws_sns_topic.online_tax_qa5_sbr_client_report" -> "[root] module.sns.provider.aws"
            "[root] module.sns.provider.aws" -> "[root] provider.aws (disabled)"
        }
}
```

The Graph has other resources which I have not provided in the tf file above. Its only the API GW that has issues. By the way, I am able to test the API from the console and it works fine. I am not able to execute it from my localbox or postman.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the case for the first deployment or just future deployments when things change? There's an open issue on GH for the latter: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6613

Comment: Even the first deployment didn't work I guess. I destroyed the entire stack and applied it again. Still don't see the deployment. When terraform plan lists all the changes that need to be applied, the deployment resource is listed at the very top. Does that mean that gets deployed first?

Comment: It absolutely won't be run first because it is dependent on at least 2 resources (`aws_api_gateway_rest_api` and `aws_api_gateway_method`) which in turn may well be dependent on other things. I'd have to run your TF to see but that will have to wait until tonight unfortunately. It might be interesting to see the output of `terraform graph` if you could edit that into your question?

Answer (score 22):

TF does not deploy the API, this link might help you: https://medium.com/coryodaniel/til-forcing-terraform-to-deploy-a-aws-api-gateway-deployment-ed36a9f60c1a

I've fixed mine by adding the variable deployed_at:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_ingest_deployment" {
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.xxx",
                "aws_api_gateway_integration.yyy",
                "aws_api_gateway_integration.zzz",
                "aws_api_gateway_integration.www",
  ]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.foo.id}"
  stage_name = "${var.environment}"

  variables {
    deployed_at = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

the downside is that if done this way it will always deploy, even if there's no change

Comment: Actually, I just checked also this GitHub issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6613

Doing it this way:

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "default" {
  ...
  stage_description = "${md5(file("api_gateway.tf"))}"
  ...
}

is more clever and will force you to deploy less

Comment: I wasted hours on this problem. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Antonio's answer helped me, the solution on this post seems 'better' (workaround, but works). Should be an accepted answer?

Comment: there no longer appears to be a `variables` block available to the resource, and the EXPORT TF_VAR_foo doesn't work anymore, either... FYI

Answer (score 12):

None of the other solutions here worked for me as I get this error:

```
BadRequestException: Active stages pointing to this deployment must be moved or deleted
```

[This is the solution](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10674#issuecomment-290767062) that worked for me:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id       = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  stage_name        = "default"
  stage_description = "Deployed at ${timestamp()}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Tested on Terraform `0.12.24`

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked for me too on TF 0.12.24

Comment: Still valid with tf 1.4.4, that's a long running workaround, thank you :)

Comment: Downside of this solution it will always force redeploy could be solved by stage_description = "${md5(file("api_gateway.tf"))}"

Answer (score 7):

old question but this thread still comes up in google.

For a possible better solution in 2022 we use the following:

Create a SHA1 hash of all the referenced resources configuration, so that any change in any attribute of the referenced resources is detected and triggers a new deployment (rather than only the ID like in the official documentation).

I have found this comment which explains it in further detail: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/162#issuecomment-532593939

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.example,
      aws_api_gateway_method.example,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.example,
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [aws_api_gateway_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment#terraform-resources):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id

  triggers = {
    # NOTE: The configuration below will satisfy ordering considerations,
    #       but not pick up all future REST API changes. More advanced patterns
    #       are possible, such as using the filesha1() function against the
    #       Terraform configuration file(s) or removing the .id references to
    #       calculate a hash against whole resources. Be aware that using whole
    #       resources will show a difference after the initial implementation.
    #       It will stabilize to only change when resources change afterwards.
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.example.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.example.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.example.id,
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

You need to define the triggers that should trigger a new deployment, I used without the `id` and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things which you need to be careful about.

1. Mention the depends on properly to make sure the deployment block is executed after the integration and method block is executed(especially when you have any authorizers in place).
2. Add the timestamp function in variables to deploy it immediately once all the dependent blocks are executed.

   ```
     resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "mydeployment" {
     depends_on =["aws_api_gateway_method.mymethod","aws_api_gateway_integration.myintegration"]
     rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.myapi.id}"
     stage_name = "dev"
     variables = {
        deployed_at = "${timestamp()}"
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To trigger redeployment on any file changes here is solution:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.url_shortner_api.id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(
      jsonencode([
        file("root_get_method.tf"),
        file("url_shortner_post_method.tf"),
        file("url_shortner_get_method.tf"),
      ])
    )
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

This will only trigger redeployment if anything changed in listed files.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the code change is at lambda level. So you may interpolate lambda code version as a variable and add it in same module where you have api deployment. This way it will deploy only when lambda code changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swagger template and terraform ver >= 0.12 then you can give swagger file for MD5 computation like below. This work perfectly.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deploy_stage" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.product_api.id
  stage_name  = var.stage_name
  stage_description = md5(file("swagger_api.yml"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue.
Had the following problem:

1. `lifecycle { create_before_destroy = false }`

I had to turn it to false, as I had an options method being added to the same uri as the get. When I tried running the build with flag as turned on was getting the following error

*Error creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method*

2. After that I started getting the issue

BadRequestException: Active stages pointing to this deployment must be moved or deleted

This upon investigation, I found to be related to the custom domain mapping happening in my terraform script. Upon manual deletion of the mapping and running the Jenkins Job solved the issue.

3. The final thing that I did was use the following script in my jenkins file before the terraform plan and terraform apply. I know its a hack, but this was the best I could come up with.

/usr/local/bin/terraform destroy -target aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping.<resource_name> -auto-approve

This solved the issue. I checked in multiple blogs where they mentioned on setting the life-cycle flag to true. But I couldn't do it as it created the above issue.