# Api gateway v2, lambda authorizer doesn’t include a route with path /*

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

So I have been trying to solve this issue for a couple of evenings by now, and I still feel that there is not really any progress.

So what I'm trying to do, is to set up a lambda authorizer for my API gateway.

I have attached my authorizer both with Terraform and through the console without any luck. For my Terraform configuration, I have something like this:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "lambda_authorizer" {
  api_id                            = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  authorizer_type                   = "REQUEST"
  identity_sources                  = ["$request.header.Authorization"]
  name                              = "lambda_authorizer-${var.app_name}-${var.environment}"
  authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = 0
  enable_simple_responses           = true
  authorizer_uri                    = aws_lambda_function.authorizer.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "my_authorizer_lambda_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.authorizer.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id}/*/*/*"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "integration" {
  api_id                 = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  integration_type       = "HTTP_PROXY"
  integration_uri        = aws_service_discovery_service.ecs-discovery-service.arn
  integration_method     = "ANY"
  connection_type        = "VPC_LINK"
  connection_id          = aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link.vpc_link.id
  payload_format_version = "1.0"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  route_key          = "ANY /{proxy+}"
  target             = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.integration.id}"
  authorization_type = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.lambda_authorizer.id
  depends_on         = [aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.lambda_authorizer]
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "stage" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  name        = "${var.app_name}-${var.environment}"
  auto_deploy = true

  default_route_settings {
    logging_level            = "INFO"
    detailed_metrics_enabled = true
    data_trace_enabled       = true
    throttling_rate_limit    = 20 #Amount of requests per second
    throttling_burst_limit   = 50 #Concurrent requests
  }
  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.api_gw_access_log_group.arn
    format = jsonencode({
      requestId               = "$context.requestId"
      sourceIp                = "$context.identity.sourceIp"
      requestTime             = "$context.requestTime"
      protocol                = "$context.protocol"
      httpMethod              = "$context.httpMethod"
      resourcePath            = "$context.resourcePath"
      routeKey                = "$context.routeKey"
      status                  = "$context.status"
      responseLength          = "$context.responseLength"
      integrationErrorMessage = "$context.integrationErrorMessage"
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Above, I left unnecessary stuff out. But the gist is, that the deployment deploys as it should and the authorizer gets attached to my API Gateway, however I encounter the following error for both creating with Terraform and AWS console: (this scr shot is for when i tried with the console with a different source_arn)

[image]

I have a hard time understanding whats actually going on here, since there is a route with path /* .....

I tried experimenting with this and figured out, that when I create a custom lambda based endpoint for the same function (not authorizer, but just an API endpoint), the error dissapears - but the problem obviously still persists... Super strange!

In continuation, I can see that the requests hits my API gateway, but nothing is printed in the Lambda logs - Which I guess is why im getting a 403 status code returned (e.g. default return if Lambda Authorizer doesn't return a policy)

Anyway, I'm stuck here without any further progress. Please help me out.

---

**Update**

I tried to change the source_arn to:

`source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/authorizers/${aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.lambda_authorizer.id}"`

Still no luck.

---

**Update 9/9**

So I tried changing the `source_arn` to account for different lambda versions:

`source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/authorizers/${aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.lambda_authorizer.id}/*/*"`

Additionally I tried:

`source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/*"`

Still looking at the same error, nor can I see that the request is hitting my lambda (only API gateway)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the possible reasons is that your Lambda had many versions, but you added the resource-based policy only to the unversioned function and not to the versioned ones.

In the terraform [`resource aws_lambda_permission`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission#basic-usage), you have to specify the qualifier argument, use the Lambda version as the value for it.

Otherwise you can also try to add `/*/*` at the end:

```
source_arn    = "source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/authorizers/${aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.lambda_authorizer.id}/*/*"
```

Comment: I did post an update, no luck :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, have you checked the first option I mentioned about adding `qualifier` to terraform resource aws_lambda_permission ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add an authorizer to an existing API GW, it does not create a deployment, and the authorizer will not change until you do so which Terraform makes it hard to do. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815786/2052550)

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted!
I'm using terragrunt but it should work the same.
For using lambda as authorizer permissions you need to specify the following in your `source_arn` field, otherwise, lambda would think your setting an integration (!=authorization).

```
source_arn   = "${dependency.api_gateway.outputs.apigatewayv2_api_execution_arn}/authorizers/*"
```

which corresponds to something like this:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:0123456789:abcdefg89/authorizers/*
```

[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee76C.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCy7p.png

***Update 13/09:***

So after lots of fails and error please discard my previous comment. This is the configuration I've ended up with:

> Background: HTTP API Gateway w/ autoDeploy, Custom Lambda Authorizer (NON-JWT) w/ publish set to true (no versions, just $LATEST).

I declare my authorizer as such (terragrunt, but same inputs for terraform):

```
  authorizers = {
    "lambda" = {
      authorizer_type                   = "REQUEST"
      identity_sources                  = "$request.header.User-Agent"
      name                              = "lambda-authorizer"
      authorizer_credentials_arn        = "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/prod.invokelambda.role"
      authorizer_uri                    = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:0123456789012:function:test_apigw-auth_lambda/invocations"
      authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
      enable_simple_responses           = true
    }
  }
```

I've used a IAM role with the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "InvokeLamdbaAuth",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:0123456789012:function:test_apigw-auth_lambda"
        }
    ]
}
```

And trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": ["apigateway.amazonaws.com", "lambda.amazonaws.com"]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

This sets up the authorizer as follows:
[Screenshot-authorizer-conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyixQ.png)

And that was enough to invoke lambda properly and all set up with IaC. No RBAC set on lambda, nor triggers.
[no-f-triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97H36.png)

Quick notes:

1. Lambda as assume trust policy - not quite sure if it's needed.
2. If you're debugging - turn on both apigw & lambda cloudwatch logs. I recommend adding `'responseType':'$context.error.responseType', 'errorMessage':'$context.error.message', 'integrationErrorMessage':'$context.integrationErrorMessage'` to your apigw log format for better understanding.
3. Use the simplest lambda auth you could work with, like the one describe in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html#http-api-lambda-authorizer.example-code), just add console.log for f sake.

Comment: Okay so apparently the UI sucks, you could have set the permissions successfully, and it still won't show as a valid trigger in the console..
Even following the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-troubleshooting-lambda.html) and using the cli for permissions got me the same results.

The only way I could have gotten the UI to look proper was to create a route in my api gateway, which corresponds to the lambda name, and integrates with it.
That plus source being 

`arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:0123456789:abcdefg89/*/*/my-lambda-authorizer-name`